# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{{ {n}\choose{k}}{ {x}\choose{k}}}{{ {y}\choose{k}}} = \frac{{ {y-x}\choose{n}}}{{ {y}\choose{n}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I need to prove this equation
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{{ {n}\choose{k}}{ {x}\choose{k}}}{{ {y}\choose{k}}} = \frac{{ {y-x}\choose{n}}}{{ {y}\choose{n}}}$$

where $x$, $y$ and $n$ are nonnegative integers satisfying $y \geq n$.

The sign $(-1)^k$ suggests using binomial expansion, I've tried this, but without success. Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you considered how you might interpret the LHS with PIE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that

$$\binom{y}n\binom{n}k=\binom{y}k\binom{y-k}{n-k}\;,$$

so

$$\binom{y}n\cdot\frac{\binom{n}k\binom{x}k}{\binom{y}k}=\binom{y-k}{n-k}\binom{x}k\;,$$

and after multiplication by $\binom{y}n$, the proposed identity reduces to

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{x}k\binom{y-k}{n-k}=\binom{y-x}n\;.\tag{1}$$

$\binom{y-x}n$ is the number of $n$-element subsets of $[y]\setminus[x]$, where as usual $[x]=\{1,\ldots,x\}$. For $k\in[x]$ let $\mathscr{A}_k$ be the family of $n$-element subsets of $[y]$ that contain $k$. Then

$$\left|\,\bigcap_{k\in I}\mathscr{A}_k\,\right|=\binom{y-|I|}{n-|I|}$$

whenever $\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[x]$, so by the inclusion-exclusion principle we have

$$\begin{align*}
\left|\,\bigcup_{k\in[x]}\mathscr{A}_k\,\right|&=\sum_{\varnothing\ne I\subseteq[x]}(-1)^{|I|+1}\binom{y-|I|}{n-|I|}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^x(-1)^{k+1}\binom{x}k\binom{y-k}{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{x}k\binom{y-k}{n-k}\;,
\end{align*}$$

assuming that $x\ge n$. (Recall that by definition $\binom{y-k}{n-k}=0$ when $n-k<0$.) This is the number of $n$-element subsets of $[y]$ that *do* intersect $[x]$, so

$$\begin{align*}\binom{y-x}n&=\binom{y}n-\left|\,\bigcup_{k\in[x]}\mathscr{A}_k\,\right|\\
&=\binom{y}n-\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{x}k\binom{y-k}{n-k}\\
&=\binom{y}n+\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\binom{x}k\binom{y-k}{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{x}k\binom{y-k}{n-k}\;,
\end{align*}$$

as desired.

**Added:** as **darij grinberg** pointed out in the comments, the combinatorial interpretation requires the assumption that $y\ge x$. For each $x$ the combinatorial argument establishes $(1)$ for each integer $y\ge x$ and each side of $(1)$ is an $n$-th degree polynomial in $y$, so $(1)$ must be a polynomial identity.

Comment: Note: You are assuming $y \geq x$. This assumption is legitimate (as a WLOG assumption) since your (reduced) identity is a polynomial identity in $y$; but this is worth mentioning explicitly.

Comment: @darij: Aargh! Yes, of course. I have *no* idea what I was thinking. I’ll add suitable commentary in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Standing the conditions you gave, the $y \choose n$ is not null, and we can multiply by it  both sides, giving
$$
\left( \begin{gathered}
  y - x \\ 
  n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \begin{gathered}
  y \\ 
  n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  x \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)/\left( \begin{gathered}
  y \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} 
$$
The RHS can be developed as

> $$
> \begin{gathered}
>   \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \begin{gathered}
>   y \\ 
>   n \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
>   n \\ 
>   k \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
>   x \\ 
>   k \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)/\left( \begin{gathered}
>   y \\ 
>   k \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)}  =  \hfill  \\
>    = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \begin{gathered}
>   y \\ 
>   k \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
>   y - k \\ 
>   n - k \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
>   x \\ 
>   k \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)/\left( \begin{gathered}
>   y \\ 
>   k \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)}  =  \hfill  \\
>    = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( \begin{gathered}
>   y - k \\ 
>   n - k \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
>   x \\ 
>   k \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)}  =  \hfill   \\
>    = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k\, \leqslant \,n} {\left( \begin{gathered}
>   y - k \\ 
>   n - k \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
>   k - x - 1 \\ 
>   k \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right)}  =  \hfill    \\
>    = \left( \begin{gathered}
>   y - x \\ 
>   n \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right) \hfill \\ 
> \end{gathered} 
> $$
>   which is valid for $x$ and $y$ even complex, with the only condition that ${y \choose n }\ne 0$.

- ---Note ----*

1st step) *Trinomial Revision* :
$\left( \begin{gathered}
  y \\ 
  n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) = \left( \begin{gathered}
  y \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  y - k \\ 
  n - k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)$

2nd step) simplifying $ {y \choose k }$

3rd step) *VanderMonde Convolution*

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation based upon *[Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity#Chu.E2.80.93Vandermonde_identity)*. It is convenient to simplify OPs identity 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{{ {n}\choose{k}}{ {x}\choose{k}}}{{ {y}\choose{k}}} = \frac{{ {y-x}\choose{n}}}{{ {y}\choose{n}}}
\end{align*}

by multiplying both sides with $\binom{y}{n}$ and

> we claim
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{x}{k}\binom{y-k}{n-k}=\binom{y-x}{n}
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{x}{k}\binom{y-k}{n-k}&=(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{x}{k}\binom{n-y-1}{n-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=(-1)^n\binom{x+n-y-1}{n}\tag{2}\\
> &=\binom{y-x}{n}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply to $\binom{y-k}{n-k}$ the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$
- In (2) we apply *[Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity#Chu.E2.80.93Vandermonde_identity)* to the right-hand series in (1)
- In (3) we  apply  the binomial identity from (1) to $\binom{x+n-y-1}{n}$

Comment: Nice and compact Markus (+1)! by applying the *Upper Negation*  twice you got same result as in my answer quicker.

Comment: @GCab: Many thanks, GCab. Two aspects regarding your answer: It looks somewhat uncommon, that the equality chain starts and ends with the same expression. Maybe you could simply skip the leftmost expression. The last step in the equality chain is (for me) not that obvious. Maybe you could add a small comment to ease reading.Then your answer is for sure a good candidate for upvotes. Regards,

Comment: Thanks Markus, accept your suggestions. I tried and make more readable my answer.  By the way, on this topic,  I would like to know your opinion concerning answer to [question 2064742](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064742/)