# Show that $-{C_{x-2}\over {2x-1\choose x}}=1-{x-1\over x+1}(2^2)+{(x-1)(x-2)\over (x+1)(x+2) }(3^2)-\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers

$C_{k}={1\over 1+k}{2k\choose k}$; it is the k-th Catalan numbers

$x\ge2$

$$-{C_{x-2}\over {2x-1\choose x}}=1-{x-1\over x+1}(2^2)+{(x-1)(x-2)\over (x+1)(x+2)}(3^2)-{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\over (x+1)(x+2)(x+3)}(4^2)+\cdots$$

How can we prove this series?

I try: can't think of any ideas

I just wonder if we can simplify ${(x-1)(x-2)\over (x+1)(x+2)}$ into a simple polynomial expression.

We can use [Faling and rising factorials](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)

$$-{C_{x-2}\over {2x-1\choose x}}=1-{(x)_2\over x^{(2)}}(2^2)+{(x)_3\over x^{(3)}}(3^2)-{(x)_4\over x^{(4)}}(4^2)+\cdots$$

$${(x)_n\over x^{(n)}}={{x\choose n}\over {x+n-1\choose n}}$$

$$-{C_{x-2}\over {2x-1\choose x}}=1-{{x\choose 2}\over {x+1\choose 2}}(2^2)+{{x\choose 3}\over {x+2\choose 3}}(3^2)-\cdots$$

From here I can't go further. Can anyone help me to prove this series?

A hint from @Thomas

$$-{x\over 2(2x-1)(2x-3)}=1-{{x\choose 2}\over {x+1\choose 2}}(2^2)+{{x\choose 3}\over {x+2\choose 3}}(3^2)-\cdots$$

Comment: I just correct some mistakes

Comment: You might simplify the left side using:
$$\binom{2x-1}{x}=\frac{2(2x-1)(2x-3)}{x}C_{x-2}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested by *@Thomas*, the RHS can be transformed into one of these forms
$$
\begin{gathered}
   - \frac{{C_{\,x - 2} }}
{{\left( \begin{gathered}
  2x - 1 \\ 
  x \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)}} =  - \frac{1}
{{x - 1}}\left( \begin{gathered}
  2\left( {x - 2} \right) \\ 
  \left( {x - 2} \right) \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)/\left( \begin{gathered}
  2x - 1 \\ 
  x \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) =  \hfill \\
   =  - \frac{{\left( {2\left( {x - 2} \right)} \right)^{\,\underline {\,x - 2\,} } x!}}
{{\left( {x - 1} \right)\left( {x - 2} \right)!\left( {2x - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,x\,} } }} =  - \frac{{\left( {2x - 4} \right)^{\,\underline {\,x - 2\,} } x}}
{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,x\,} } }} =  \hfill \\
   =  - \frac{{\left( {x - 1} \right)x}}
{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,3\,} } }} =  - \frac{{x^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } }}
{{\left( {2x - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,3\,} } }} =  - \frac{x}
{{2\left( {2x - 1} \right)\left( {2x - 3} \right)}} =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{1}
{{8\left( {2x - 1} \right)}} - \frac{3}
{{8\left( {2x - 3} \right)}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}   \tag{1}
$$

The RHS can instead be developed in one of these forms
$$
\begin{gathered}
  f(x) = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( {k + 1} \right)^{\,2} \frac{{x^{\,\underline {\,k + 1\,} } }}
{{x^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} } }}}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( {k + 1} \right)^{\,2} \left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - \,\left( {k + 1} \right)\,} } x^{\,\underline {\,k + 1\,} } }  =  \hfill \\
   =  - \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\frac{{\left( {k + 1} \right)^{\,2} x^{\,\underline {\,k + 1\,} } }}
{{\left( { - x} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k + 1\,} } }}}  =  - \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( {k + 1} \right)^{\,2} \frac{{\Gamma (x + 1)\Gamma ( - x - k)}}
{{\Gamma (x - k)\Gamma ( - x + 1)}}}  =  - \frac{{\Gamma (x + 1)}}
{{\Gamma ( - x + 1)}}\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( {k + 1} \right)^{\,2} \frac{{\Gamma ( - x - k)}}
{{\Gamma (x - k)}}}  =  \hfill \\
   = \Gamma (x + 1)\Gamma (x)\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \frac{{\left( {k + 1} \right)^{\,2} }}
{{\Gamma (x - k)\Gamma (x + k + 1)}}}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
where the latter turns useful to check for convergence.
We will focalize our attention on the first form on the second line.

Let's premise that for $z,w,a \in C$ and within the definition domain of the Rising and Falling Factorials we have
$$
\frac{{\left( {z + a} \right)^{\,\underline {\,w\,} } }}
{{z^{\,\underline {\,w\,} } }}\, = \frac{{\left( {z + a} \right)^{\,\underline {\,a\,} } }}
{{\left( {z + a - w} \right)^{\,\underline {\,a\,} } }}\quad \quad z^{\,\overline {\, - w\,} }  = \frac{1}
{{\left( {z - w} \right)^{\,\overline {\,w\,} } }} = \frac{1}
{{\left( {z - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,w\,} } }}
$$
by which we can transform the addenda, leaving out for the moment the $(k+1)^2$ factor, as

> $$
> \begin{gathered}
>   h(x,k)\quad \left| \begin{gathered}
>   \;x \in \;\mathbb{C}\; \hfill \\
>   \;k \in \;\;\mathbb{Z} \hfill \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right.\quad  = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \frac{{x^{\,\underline {\,k + 1\,} } }}
> {{x^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} } }} =  - \frac{{x^{\,\underline {\,k + 1\,} } }}
> {{\left( { - x} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k + 1\,} } }} =  - \frac{{\left( { - x + 2x} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k + 1\,} } }}
> {{\left( { - x} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k + 1\,} } }} =  \hfill \\
>    =  - \frac{{\left( { - x + 2x} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2x\,} } }}
> {{\left( { - x + 2x - k - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2x\,} } }} =  - \frac{{x^{\,\underline {\,2x\,} } }}
> {{\left( {x - k - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2x\,} } }} =  - x^{\,\underline {\,2x\,} } \left( {x - k} \right)^{\,\overline {\, - 2x\,} }  =  \hfill \\
>    =  - x^{\,\underline {\,2x\,} } \left( { - x - k - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - \,2x\,} }  \hfill \\ 
> \end{gathered}    \tag{2}
> $$

Now we have an expression where the summation index appears
only in the base of the Falling Factorial and we know the *Indefinite Summation*
(*Anti-Delta*) of such an expression, which is
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \sum\nolimits_{\,z} {z^{\,\underline {\,w\,} } }  = \Delta _{\,z} ^{\, - 1} \,z^{\,\underline {\,w\,} }  = \frac{1}
{{w + 1}}\,z^{\,\underline {\,w + 1\,} }  + c \hfill \\
  \sum\nolimits_{\,z} {\left( { - z} \right)^{\,\underline {\,w\,} } }  = \Delta _{\,z} ^{\, - 1} \left( { - z} \right)^{\,\underline {\,w\,} }  =  - \frac{1}
{{w + 1}}\left( { - z + 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,w + 1\,} }  + c \hfill \\
  \sum\nolimits_{\;z\, = \,0}^{\;\infty } {\left( { - z + a} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - \,w\,} } }  = \frac{1}
{{1 - w}}\left( {a + 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,1 - w\,} } \quad \left| {\;0 < \operatorname{Re} \left( w \right)} \right. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}    \tag{3}
$$
since it is
$$
z^{\,\underline {\,w\,} } \, \approx \left| z \right|^{\,\operatorname{Re} (w)} \quad \left| {\;z\, \to \,\infty ,\;\;\left| {\,\arg (z)\,} \right| < \pi } \right.
$$

Therefore what we have to do is to express $(k+1)^2$ in a form that can be aggregated to the factorial, i.e.
$$
\left( {k + 1} \right)^{\,2}  = \left( {x - x - k - 1} \right)^{\,2}  = \left( { - x - k + 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2\,} }  + \left( {2x - 3} \right)\left( { - x - k} \right)^{\,\underline {\,1\,} }  + \left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,2} 
$$

So we can proceed with the final steps

> $$
> \begin{gathered}
>   f(x) = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \left( {k + 1} \right)^{\,2} \frac{{x^{\,\underline {\,k + 1\,} } }}
> {{x^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} } }}}  =  \hfill \\
>    = \;\; - x^{\,\underline {\,2x\,} } \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - x - k + 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2\,} } \left( { - x - k - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - \,2x\,} } }  +  \hfill \\
>    - x^{\,\underline {\,2x\,} } \left( {2x - 3} \right)\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - x - k} \right)^{\,\underline {\,1\,} } \left( { - x - k - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - \,2x\,} } }  +  \hfill \\
>    - x^{\,\underline {\,2x\,} } \left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,2} \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - x - k - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - \,2x\,} } } \;\; =  \hfill \\
>    = \;\; - x^{\,\underline {\,2x\,} } \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - x - k + 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2 - 2x\,} } }  +  \hfill \\
>    - x^{\,\underline {\,2x\,} } \left( {2x - 3} \right)\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - x - k} \right)^{\,\underline {\,1 - 2x\,} } }  +  \hfill \\
>    - x^{\,\underline {\,2x\,} } \left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,2} \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( { - x - k - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - \,2x\,} } }  =  \hfill \\
>    = x^{\,\underline {\,2x\,} } \left( \begin{gathered}
>   \frac{1}
> {{2x - 3}}\left( { - x + 2} \right)^{\,\underline {\,3 - 2x\,} }  +  \hfill \\
>   \frac{{\left( {2x - 3} \right)}}
> {{2x - 2}}\left( { - x + 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2 - 2x\,} }  +  \hfill \\
>   \frac{{\left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,2} }}
> {{2x - 1}}\left( { - x} \right)^{\,\underline {\,1 - 2x\,} }  \hfill \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right) =  \hfill \\
>    = x^{\,\underline {\,2x\,} } \left( { - x + 1} \right)\left( { - x} \right)^{\,\underline {\,1 - 2x\,} } \left( {\frac{{\left( { - x + 2} \right)}}
> {{2x - 3}} + \frac{{\left( {2x - 3} \right)}}
> {{2x - 2}} + \frac{{\left( { - x + 1} \right)}}
> {{2x - 1}}} \right) =  \hfill \\
>    =  - \frac{{x^{\,\underline {\,2x\,} } \left( { - x} \right)^{\,\underline {\,1 - 2x\,} } }}
> {{2\left( {2x - 3} \right)\left( {2x - 1} \right)}} =  \hfill \\
>    =  - \frac{{x^{\,\underline {\,2x\,} } }}
> {{\left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,2x - 1\,} } 2\left( {2x - 3} \right)\left( {2x - 1} \right)}} =  \hfill \\
>    =  - \frac{x}
> {{2\left( {2x - 3} \right)\left( {2x - 1} \right)}}\quad \left| {\;1 < \operatorname{Re} (x)} \right. \hfill \\ 
> \end{gathered}   \tag{4}
> $$

which compared with (1) provides the Q.E.D.

*--- Note ---*

As per the comment by *Markus*, it shall be noted that, for $x \in \mathbb N$,
the expressions given above shall be taken in the limit.
Consider for ex. $x=2$ , then:
$$
h(2,k) = \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} \frac{{2^{\,\underline {\,k + 1\,} } }}
{{2^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} } }} = 1, - \frac{1}
{3},0, \cdots \quad \left| {\;k = 0,1,2, \cdots } \right.
$$
and
$$
\begin{gathered}
  h(2,k) =  - 2^{\,\underline {\,4\,} } \left( { - 2 - k - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - \,4\,} }  =  - \frac{{2^{\,\underline {\,4\,} } }}
{{\left( {2 - k - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,4\,} } }} =  \hfill \\
   =  - \frac{{ - 2/\bar \infty }}
{{2/\bar \infty }}, - \frac{{ - 2/\bar \infty }}
{{ - 6/\bar \infty }}, - \frac{{ - 2/\bar \infty }}
{{24}}, \cdots  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

Comment: A really nice derivation. It is instructive and creative, so (+1). But It seems it is not correct for the most important case, namely for $x\geq 2, x\in\mathbb{N}$. Note that $f(2)=-\frac{1}{3}$. Now, according to (2) above we obtain $f(2)=1^2h(2,0)+2^2h(2,1)$. But, since $x^{\underline{2x}}=0$ for $x\geq 2, x\in\mathbb{N}$ we  get $h(x,k)=0$ and therefore $1^2h(2,0)+2^2(2,1)=0$ instead of $-\frac{1}{3}$. It seems the transformation $x^{\underline{2x}}$ cancels the summands.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer, thanks for your comment indeed, I was sure you could provide a valuable check. Actually I checked the validity of the expression for $h$, but algebraically ( for a generic $x$): I will work on the discrepancy you pinpointed (it is possibly a matter of taking the limit for integral $x$).

Comment: @MarkusScheuer, it is in fact a matter to take the limit of the indefinite forms $0/0$.

Comment: Nice add-on. It looks fine! Really good work!  :-)