# A certain binomial transform

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

The problem is to show the equality
$$\sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \frac{\binom{a}{k}}{\binom{b}{k} } = \frac{\binom{b-a}{n}}{\binom{b}{n}}$$

where $a$, $b$ are parameters.

This identity appears in Prudnikov, Brychkov, Marichev, Integrals and series, Vol I, 4.2.10.

The sequence on the left is the (involutive) [binomial transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform) of the sequence

$$\frac{\binom{a}{n}}{\binom{b}{n}}$$

Here is a sketch of a proof involving exponential generating functions.

The exponential generating function of $\frac{\binom{a}{n}}{\binom{b}{n}}$ is

$$F(x) = \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{\binom{a}{n}}{\binom{b}{n}} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$
and this equals the [confluent hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function) $\ _1F_1(-a, -b, x)$.

Now, the exponential generating function of the transformed sequence is
$$G(x) = \exp x\cdot  F(-x)$$

Now we use a [Kummer's transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Kummer%27s_transformation) and get the result.

I wonder if there are other proofs that do not use advanced stuff like hypergeometric functions. One may assume that $a$, $b$ are integers ( natural numbers). Maybe there is even a combinatorial interpretation.  Thank you for your interest, I'd appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{{ {n}\choose{k}}{ {x}\choose{k}}}{{ {y}\choose{k}}} = \frac{{ {y-x}\choose{n}}}{{ {y}\choose{n}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064164/prove-that-sum-k-0n-1k-frac-n-choosek-x-choosek-y-cho) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%5Cge%200%7D(-1)%5Ek%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Cbinom%7Ba%7D%7Bk%7D%7D%7B%5Cbinom%7Bb%7D%7Bk%7D%7D%3D%5Cfrac%7B%5Cbinom%7Bb-a%7D%7Bn%7D%7D%7B%5Cbinom%7Bb%7D%7Bn%7D%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: Note the proposed duplicate question has an explicit upper limit of $n$. However, I assume that is what your summation intends because, if there were no upper limit, then with $k \gt b$, the denominator of $\binom{b}{k}$ in the summation would usually be specified (to the best of my knowledge) to be $0$.

Comment: @John Omielan: Thank you! So it's a duplicate question. I'd better close it .